# Kill/Debug own process from command line without root access

Tags: android, debugging, process, kill

I run at tablet own application. Sometimes I want stop or enable debug process:
[image]

How I can this without root access from command line?

Now I can stop process, but only with root access:

```
adb shell "su -c 'killall com.my.package'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have only rooted devices for debug :)

About enable debug application from cmd line.. I try use `adb shell am set-debug-app <package>`. But this way work not as I want. After this command my process stopped and after next start, yes, application was started under debug. But I want enable debug without restart process.